# How can I learn the English sounds that don't exist in my mother tongue?

Tags: pronunciation, vowels, symbols

How can I learn the English sounds that don't exist in my mother tongue? I have troubles with distingushing between the long and short sounds, but also it's very hard for me to get the difference between **rug** and **rag** and **bold** and **bald** and so on.

I know I should practice. And I do - I watch movies and I talk a lot at work. But I would be grateful for any practical tips or books which cover the topic very well.

Comment: Easily confused words are not a big problem depending of context. For instance, *Look at that bald guy*, you don't say *that **bold** guy.*

Comment: @Subjunctive, I know I can live with that and it's easy to figure out the right word out of the context. But I don't want to sound crude to native speakers and people who distinguish these sounds.

Comment: If you do not wish to appear crude to native speakers, edit your question and change *english* to *English* since in *English* (not *english*) that is how we write it.

Comment: I have an experimental training program which I believe can enhance your listening in another language, especially when that "another language" is very different from your native tongue, but it takes a lot of patience. If you're interested in it, contact me in one of our [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22937/ells-cabin) [rooms](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24938/language-overflow). (It's okay if you decide not to, btw. :-) You may be interested in a similar, but more well-known technique called [shadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speech_shadowing).

Comment: @NES, thank you for your remark:) I edited the question.

Comment: Look for "accent reduction" or "accent and pronunciation" courses. I know community colleges near me (in southern California) offer them.

Comment: @Subjunctive: I expect if you were played recordings of many different native speakers saying just the 4th word, you wouldn't be able tell for sure if they'd said ***bawd*** or ***bored*** (or even something completely different).

Comment: Watch "Sesame Street." I'm serious - children's shows will help with enunciation.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Of course that's hard regarding songs!

Answer (score 1):

A book will probably not help you since there is no way to **hear** the sounds.

These days, there are many dictionary applications and websites which **sound out** words, and of course, there is always Google translate (though it may sound a bit robotic).

There is also the possibility of forming a close relationship with a native speaker...

Comment: I can look up the words **bold** and **bald** in an online dictionary, but it doesn't help me since I hear no difference. And forming a close relationship with a native speaker just to improve my English doesn't seem fair to me.

Comment: @user2738748 But that depends of the dictionary if it has a speaker for the word to be heard. For instance, WordReference allows that and gives you a clear difference on pronunciation.

Comment: You could hire a tutor specifically for pronunciation and diction instead of general language lessons.  Another thought might be if you have a more recent Apple appliance, you could speak to Siri and see if it understands you, it will point you in the direction of **standard** American pronunciation (there is a viral video of Scots trapped in a voice activated elevator, hysterical)

Comment: I'm not sure if using Siri is always a good idea, because, as far as I can tell, Siri guesses a lot too, though it's very good. I have the same feeling when I try Apple Voice Input in my first language, too. It's good for things we speak in typical conversations, but it's not very good when I dictate technical stuff (though it's not that bad either, but when it comes to speech input, even 5% error can be annoying already).

Comment: Another way to think about it: if you are also interested in the **cultural** aspects of how the language is used, many native speakers would be more than happy to help explain the **meaning** and also the **intonations** used (and as a by product the **pronunciation**). **Intonations** are a big part of meaning and context in speaking. I'm sure they would not feel used.